# active class is not add on label field in login form autofill in material design?

Tags: javascript, jquery, material-design

I have use Material Design for login form. It's work fine but problem already autofill from time is not add active class in label. Any idea how to fix problem?
My problem is same as: https://github.com/FezVrasta/bootstrap-material-design/issues/559

HTML:

```
<form autocomplete="off" method="POST" name="signup-form" action="<?= base_url('do_login') ?>" id="login_form" class="signup-form" novalidate>
                        <div class="wpb_row vc_row vc_row-fluid">
                            <div class="vc_col-md-9 vc_col-md-offset-2 vc_col-sm-12 vc_col-sm-offset-0 wpb_column column_container">
                                <div class="wpb_row vc_row vc_row-fluid">
                                    <div class="vc_col-sm-6 wpb_column column_container">
                                        <div class="md-form">
                                            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" class="form-control" aria-invalid="false">
                                            <label for="email" class="">Email<span>*</span></label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="vc_col-sm-6 wpb_column column_container">
                                        <div class="md-form">
                                            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" class="form-control" aria-invalid="false">
                                            <label for="password" class="">Password<span>*</span></label>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                                    <div class="vc_col-sm-6 wpb_column column_container"> <button type="Submit" class="mk-btn mk-button--size-medium">Login</button> </div>
                                    <div class="vc_col-sm-6 wpb_column column_container"><p> Don't have an account? <a href="<?= base_url('sign-up') ?>">Sign Up here</a> </p></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Comment: How can we possibly have any ideas without seeing any kind of code?

Comment: Why to give minus votes?

Comment: @Luca after click to add active class on label field but login form open autofill that's way is not work active class in label field. I have use material design.